# I just need tips with "searching" and "displaying data" in my code. Any hints?

Tags: vb.net

In my code i have 4 buttons. Im having problems with my "search button" (button 2) and my "view data button" (button 4). I keep getting errors that i cant seem to fix. I just wanted to know if someone would be able to help me. thank you in advance.
the details are written in between the code so you can see where exactly im having problems.

```
 Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pInventory As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText("product.txt")
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill in required fields", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        Else
            pInventory.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text & ", $" & TextBox2.Text & ", " & TextBox3.Text)
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            Dim num As Integer
            For num = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                pInventory.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items(num))
            Next
            pInventory.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

'Here im having trouble searching for a product that is entered/saved in the data entry
        'it tells me that the exception was unhandled. it says its an invalid argument

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim name As String
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim max As Integer
        name = InputBox("What item would you like to search for :", "Product Search")
        num = 0
        max = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
```

''''''''''''''''''''THE PROBLEM IS HERE WITH (num

```
 Do While (name <> (ListBox1.Items.Item(num))) And (num < max)
        num = num + 1

        ListBox1.Items.Add(num)
    Loop
    If (name = ListBox1.Items.Item(num)) Then
        MsgBox(name & " Was found", , "Search")
    Else
        MsgBox(name & " Was not found", , "Search")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Else
        MsgBox("Please make a selection")
    End If
End Sub
```

'Here, when you click on the button4 ("view data") button i just want the archive to show everything entered in data entry
        'but i just cant seem how to do it to where it just displays the data instead of asking you to enter archive name
        'i think im just worn out with this project!

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
 Dim item As String
        Dim product As StreamReader
        item = InputBox("Please enter archive name", "Product List")
        item = item & ".txt"
        If File.Exists(item) Then
            product = File.OpenText(item)
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            Do While product.Peek <> -1
                ListBox1.Items.Add(product.ReadLine)
            Loop
            product.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("Archive does not exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please keep in mind that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of words that are in your question title isn't going to help categorize your question.  Always remember to include a language tag!

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While (name <> (ListBox1.Items.Item(num))) And (num < max)
```

At the above code, if your ListBox doesn't contain any item yet `ListBox1.Items.Item(num)` will trigger exception, **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**. You can add condition to make sure ListBox1 contains some Items:

```
Do While (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso name <> (ListBox1.Items.Item(num))) And (num < max)
```

---

On Button4 clicked, you want to display all data in file without asking for file name? If that is the case, you can just hardcode the file name in a global constant declared in Module level, then you can get the file name from that constant whenever you need it, like:

```
Public Const ArchieveName As String = "Product.txt"
...

item = ArchieveName
```

You did hardcode file name on Button1 click event too.

Comment: so do you think i should hardcode it as a global variable? Can i even do that? sry im a beginner still, i hope thats not a dumb question.

Comment: @RR Whether to hardcode the file/archieve name or ask user to input it is depend on your requirement. Since your existing code is already work for the later scenario and you seems didn't like it, I suggest a way for the other scenario, hardcode. And common practice for hardcoded values those aren't expected to change at run-time is declaring them as [Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb8fth98.aspx)